# Which things should be called with `after_setup_theme`?

Tags: hooks

I just read about the existence of `after_setup_theme` in [this blog post](https://alexwright.net/blog/web-design/responsive-images-wordpress/). I'm not experienced in Wordpress development, so I was wondering if there exists some kind of list with all the things that should be in called with `after_setup_theme`?

I can't find good documentation about it, so can you also explain something about the function itself and what the best way is to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`after_setup_theme` is a wordpress hook which fires after the theme is loaded

after_setup_theme runs before init and is generally used to initialize theme settings/options before a user is authenticated. According to the Codex: This is the first action hook available to themes, triggered immediately after the active theme's functions.

Comment: Hi @nikhilHadvani thanks for you answer. Is after_setup_theme only called once ever? And what things should be called with it?